# Change attribute of multiple elements on hover by using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div elements which are placed next to each other, i want to change the attribute `background-color` of both of them if the user hovers over one of them.

So the background-color should be initially set to `#d8d8d8` for both divs and should change to `#cacaca` on both divs if i hover over one of the divs.

I solved it using jquery:

```js
$("#FOO").hover
(
  function()
  {
      $(this).css("background-color","#CACACA");
      $("#BAR").css("background-color","#CACACA");
  },
  function()
  {
     $(this).css("background-color","#D8D8D8");
     $("#BAR").css("background-color","#D8D8D8");
  }
)

$("#BAR").hover
(
  function()
  {
      $(this).css("background-color","#CACACA");
      $("#FOO").css("background-color","#CACACA");
  },
  function()
  {
     $(this).css("background-color","#D8D8D8");
     $("#FOO").css("background-color","#D8D8D8");
  }
)
```

```css
.buttons {
  border:1px solid black; 
  background-color: #D8D8D8;

  height: 100px;

  font-family: play;
  font-size: 30px;

  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-10 buttons" id="FOO" style="border-right: 0px">
  <span style="padding-left:100px">FOO</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 buttons" id="BAR" style="border-left: 0px">
  <span>BAR</span>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Maybe only with css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap columns in `div` and add `:hover` on it:

```css
.buttons {
  border:1px solid black; 
  background-color: #D8D8D8;

  height: 100px;

  font-family: play;
  font-size: 30px;

  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px; 
}

.row:hover > .buttons {
    background-color: #CACACA;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-10 buttons" id="FOO" style="border-right: 0px">
    <span style="padding-left:100px">FOO</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 buttons" id="BAR" style="border-left: 0px">
    <span>BAR</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would give both divs the same css-class like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 buttons buttonset1" id="FOO" style="border-right: 0px">
  <span style="padding-left:100px">FOO</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 buttons buttonset1" id="BAR" style="border-left: 0px">
  <span>BAR</span>
</div>
```

Then in jquery you can make the following rule:

```
$(".buttonset1").hover
(
  function()
  {
      $(".buttonset1").css("background-color","#CACACA");
  },
  function()
  {
      $(".buttonset1").css("background-color","#D8D8D8");
  }
)
```

You are more flexible this way.

Comment: common class `.buttons` was already there and he want to use CSS not JS

Comment: @GauravAggarwal indeed buttons is already present but if you want to have multiple sets of buttongroups, then you need to differentate. Also he did not state he want to use css, he asked if its maybe possible with css. I think a css-solution is more elegant but not as flexible.